# How to alert when a server gets removed in Azure?

Tags: azure

Is there a way to send a notification when a server gets destroyed in Azure ? I need this to be at the subscription level and not at the server or resource group level.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an Azure Activity log at the subscription level. There is a log category *Delete*. You can create alert log based on it.